# Does Teradata support -Multiple With Clause?

Tags: sql, teradata, with-clause

Trying to execute in SQLAssitant (v 15.x Teradata):

```
WITH   TEMP1 (EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL) AS (WITH TEMP (EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL) AS (SELECT EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL FROM EMP_TABLE_TEST)
SELECT EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL FROM TEMP) SELECT EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL FROM TEMP1
```

Error: SELECT Failed. 6926: definitions, views, triggers or stored procedure

```
WITH TEMP (EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL) AS (SELECT EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL FROM EMP_TABLE_TEST ) , TEMP1  (EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL) AS (
SELECT EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL FROM TEMP) SELECT  EMP_ID,E_NAME,E_SAL FROM TEMP1
```

Error: SELECT Failed. 3807: Object 'TEMP' does not exist.

Does Teradata really support Multiple WITH clause or WITH within WITH clause?

I heard it is supported in 14.x higher version but it is not supporting for 15.x.

Comment: Did you try Google? it is a great tool to find answers.

Comment: http://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Defining-two-derived-tables-using-WITH-clause/td-p/46164

Comment: I was expecting 15.x will support with query.. but it is no..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is different (and is the same as in other databases)
`With t1 as (...),t2 as (...), t3 as (...) select ...`

---

Currently the reference order is upside-down -
t2 can refer t3 and t1 can refer t2 and t3.
The "right" order will be supported in TD16.

Comment: Can i ?  With t1 as (Select..from ABC.),t2 as (Select...from t1), t3 as (Select.. from t2.) select ...from t3. my requirement is like this..?

Comment: As I wrote, you should change the order: `with t3 as ...,t2 as...,t1 as... Select`

Comment: Thanks Dudu Markovitz, your answer worked for me.. it would be better if teradata would have supported in order like Netezza, PostGre....etc..

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Teradata 16. Please see the release summary chapter 2.

http://www.info.teradata.com/doclist.cfm?RetainParams=Y&FilterCall=Y&selDocType=100

> Previously, when a nonrecursive WITH clause defined multiple CTEs, a CTE could only reference a
>   subsequent CTE in the WITH clause. Now, a CTE can reference a preceding or subsequent CTE in the
>   WITH clause.

From Teradata Release Summary for version 16